# Hosting ASP.Net with HTML5 JS and Twitter Bootstrap formats differently

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, iis, twitter-bootstrap

In my development environemnt everything is appearing perfectly fine, I have a pie chart which uses a canvas and animation this appears fine when hosting through the browser.

I am also using Twitter Bootstrap and have a nav bar at the top of the page, which has two items.

Here are some examples:

In development Environment

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtC5J.png

Hosting in IIS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNLkg.png

After dismissing the IIS version, the error remains constant, also you can notice the rounding of the button isn't quite the same.

We are hosting on IIS6 with default settings so wondering if anything has to be done on the site to encorporate this properly? I'm not registering the .LESS anywhere I don't think so not sure if that's what could be causing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're viewing them in the same browser?  One looks like IE9+ (with rounded corners) and the other looks like an older version.

Comment: Are you getting any client script or rendering errors?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing. My application displays differently on a server (IIS6) with IE8 and viewing it on localhost with IE8. The colors appear slightly different, and all buttons are missing their border color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the X-UA-Compatible meta tag in order to fix this.
Add the following meta tag to your header in your web page and the problem should be solved

This will make sure it will look the same in development and in IIS. ( using the same browser )

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

You can also add following directive in your web.config to add a custom header application wide instead of the per page meta tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This behavior is caused because IE renders intranet sites in compatibility modus by default. ( because Microsoft thinks a lot of intranet sites are outdated, i guess)
You can modify this by going to Tools –> Compatibility ViewSettings.

References:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/12/pages-in-ie-render-differently-when-served-through-the-asp-net-development-server-and-production-server.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: One could even use `chrome=1` as explained [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/#TOC-Making-Your-Pages-Work-With-Google-Chrome-Frame) or check the [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc288325.aspx).

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me. For others reference, here's the [documentation on X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Amazing! it just woks now Thank you +1 is given

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using LESS, is that correct? If so, like you mentioned, you need to set it up in IIS to use the *twitter boostrap* if you're using those features that require LESS.

I've had similar issues with IIS and have it properly recognize file extensions when they aren't defaults in IIS.

Chances are that your *localhost* isn't as protective about file mappings or you're using a different version of IIS locally than IIS6 and it already allows the *.less* extension.

To fix this, you need to add in the extension / mapping to IIS6.

**Short version**

- Open web application properties
- Click **Configuration...**
- Under the **Mappings** tab, click **Add**
- **Executable**: Enter the same value that is setup for the ASPX extension under the Mappings tab
- **Extension**: .less
- **Verbs**: Check: Limit To, Enter: GET,HEAD
- **Script Engine**: Checked
- **Verify that file exists**: Un-checked

Graphical version if it helps anyone: Here is a link with details that I've reproduced below in case it disappears.

http://wiki.uiowa.edu/display/~mbergal/2012/06/08/Configuring+IIS+6+to+support+dotlesscss+(LESS+CSS)

**Go to the properties of the site.**

[image]

**Open the configuration**

[image]

**Add the extension**

[image]

[image]